# Creating multiple LinkedIn Application Ids (for each mobile app)

Tags: authentication, mobile, oauth, linkedin-api

I need to launch multiple apps (ios and android) and I need to set up a LinkedIn App (AppId) for authentication on each mobile App.

- Is there any way to do this in an automated way (API?)?
- Is there any kind of limit or problem with this kind of approach?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thats why they have made OAuth...You create your client from Linkedins server and feel free to use it :D

Comment: Check out if they have a limit call rate on the API